# How does BigQuery manage a struct field in a SELECT

Tags: sql, struct, google-bigquery

The following queries a struct from a public data source:

```
SELECT year FROM `bigquery-public-data.words.eng_gb_1gram` LIMIT 1000
```

Its schema is:

[image]

And the resultset is:

[image]

It seems BigQuery automatically translates a struct to all its (leaf) fields when accessed, is that correct? Or how does BigQuery handle directly calling a struct in a select statement?

Comment: Seems you miss some lines in yout comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are going on.  You have an array of structs (aka "records").

- Each element of the array appears on a separate line in the result set.
- Each field in the struct is a separate column.

So, your results are not for a struct but for an array of structs.

You can see what happens for a single struct using:

```
select year[safe_ordinal(1)]
from . . .
```

You will get a single row for each row in the data, with the first element of the `year` array in the row.  It will have separate columns, with the names of `year.year`, `year.term_frequency` and so on.  If you wanted these as "regular" columns, you can use:

```
select year[ordinal(1)].*
from . . .
```

Then the columns are `year`, `term_frequency`, and so on.

Comment: I see, but ignoring the array item, does having `year` in the select expression do the same thing as `year.*` ?

Comment: @David542 . . . `year.*` won't work in your case, because `year` is an array.  If you it were just a struct, then `year` would return a "nested" structure with columns and `year.*` would return the fields as individual columns.

Comment: it seems it drops the outer struct namespace, but otherwise acts the same for non-nested structs: `with tbl as (select STRUCT(12345 AS street, STRUCT('Bloom' AS name, 90025 AS zip) as city, 'USA' as country) as address)select address.*, address from tbl` Is that accurate? https://imgur.com/a/j1C9alw

Comment: That is what happens if you use `address.*`.  If you just use `address`, then you get `address.` in the names.

Answer (score 1):

As you might know - RECORD can be NULLABLE - in this case it is a STRUCT and RECORD can be REPEATED - in this case it is an array of record

You can use dot-start notion with the struct to select out all its fields as you do with tables' individual rows with `SELECT * FROM tbl` or its equivalent `SELECT t.* FROM tbl t`

So, for example below code

```
with tbl as (
select struct(1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c) as col_struct, 
  [ struct(11 as x, 12 as y, 13 as z),
    struct(21, 22, 23),
    struct(31, 32, 33)
  ] as col_array
)
select col_struct.* 
from tbl
```

produces

[image]

as if those are the rows of "mini" table called `col_struct`

Same dot-star notion - does not work for arrays - if you want to output separately elements of array - you need to first to unnest that array. like in below example

```
with tbl as (
select struct(1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c) as col_struct, 
  [ struct(11 as x, 12 as y, 13 as z),
    struct(21, 22, 23),
    struct(31, 32, 33)
  ] as col_array
)
select rec
from tbl, unnest(col_array) rec
```

which outputs

[image]

And now, because each row is a struct - you can use dot-star notion

```
select rec.*
from tbl, unnest(col_array) rec
```

with output

[image]

And, finally - you can combine above as

```
select col_struct.*, rec.*
from tbl t, t.col_array rec
```

with output

[image]

Note: `from tbl t, t.col_array rec` is a shortcut for `from tbl, unnest(col_array) rec`

One more note - if you reference field name that is used in multiple places of your schema - the engine picks most outer matching one. And if by chance this matching one is within the ARRAY - you first need to unnest that array. And if this one is part of STRUCT - you need to make sure you fully qualify the path

For example - with above simplified data

```
select a from tbl  // will not work    

select col_struct.a from tbl  // will work   

select col_array.x from tbl  // will not work      

select x from tbl, unnest(col_array)  // will work
```

There are many more can be said about subject based on what exactly your use case  - but above is some hopefully helpful basics